# Internet speeds don't add

Tags: network, internet

I am downloading two files from Internet. Their combined speed would be around 80Kbps, but the activity monitor shows a huge data transfer, more than 200Kbps. I already turned off auto-update. Below is the screenshot of downloading in the browser and the activity monitor:

[image]

Please guide me; what can be wrong here? Maybe my knowledge is not accurate about this.

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "their combined speed would be around 80KBPS" - how have you calculated a network speed limit from your file sizes? Edit - I think I see, you are seeing ~80KBPS total in the two download boxes but 200 on the network?

Comment: @AliBeadle thanks for your comment

As you can see in screen shot, LibreOffice is downloading at 3.1KB/sec and cyberduck is at 4.4 KB/s but in activity monitor window in the Lower right corner it says Data received/sec 274KB
Why it is saying 274 KB? when i am downloading at combine speed of 3.1KB/s + 4.4 KB/s = 7.5 KB/s

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong here.

`Cyberduck` & `LibreOffice` downloads are displaying their average speed since the beginning of the real download operation.

`Activity Monitor` is displaying an instantaneous speed which will take into account these 2 downloads, but also all the background network traffic your Mac is always doing (ex.: `netbios`, `Bonjour`, `ntp`). This instantaneous speed is highly variable and depend mostly of this background network traffic.

Comment: Thanks @daniel for commenting, Cyberduck and libreoffice are displaying instantaneous speed because when connected to 4G internet connection, it suddenly showed speed over 500KB/s, so if the case was average than it should have gone above gradually but not at once to direct 500KB/s

Comment: and i am not aware about netbios Bonjour etc, but i have already turned off auto-update in app-store

Comment: The 500 kB/s was at startup, wasn't it?

Comment: Yes it at once went above 500 kb/s like in 3 seconds, and never came down untill donwload finished.

Comment: Then this is an average value, changing quickly at the beginning and then slower and slower.

Comment: No no no, it never slowed down after connecting to 4G.

Comment: I was talking of the speed of change of the speed and not of the speed of the bytes. An average value always change more and more slowly with time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do the comparison you're trying to do as you are comparing apples and pears.

It seems like you're comparing apples and apples because the units are the same - i.e. you're comparing kB/s with kB/s.

However in reality data packets on a network are not sent as a continuous stream that can be instantaneously measured as a specific kB/s. In practice programs will measure the amount of data sent over a period of time and calculate an average, which is what is displayed.

As different programs can select difference periods of time to average over - you cannot compare the numbers the way you're doing.